# WPF Prism and Ribbon samples/tutorials

Tags: wpf, prism, ribbon

I'm looking for a WPF prism with ribbon application samples and tutorials. I have found many that cover prism or ribbon but only a few sources provide any information about implementating those two together in one application. No course code usually in available tough. An example with a few simple modules and a classical ribbon tab control would be perfect for me to start.

Thanks for any help.

Regards,
Enzo.

**Edit:**
I should add that by combining the two I want to be able to load different modules depending on the ribbon tab selected by user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find some info on a customized region adapter for the WPF Ribbon Preview [here](http://blog.joachim.at/?p=44).

Regarding the loading of modules on demand in Prism, [here is another link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707852.aspx), covering the topic.

Answer (score 3):

David Veeneman wrote a nice article about Ribbon & Prism on CodeProject
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ViewSwitchingAppsPrism4.aspx

It includes RegionAdapter for Ribbon .

Answer (score 2):

There is "[Southridge Hands-On Labs](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Southridge%20Lab)" on Codeplex (download on [WPF futures](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/14962) page). It is quite extensive, but documentation and source code are not in sync (it looks they updated labs source, but not accompanying documentation), so it can be a pain sometimes to get what is going on.

It is based on Microsoft's [WPF Ribbon Preview](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Ribbon%20Preview&ProjectName=wpf) library.

**Edit:**
I am not aware about any tutorial that covers both. You can check [series of videos on Prism and Silverlight by Mike Taulty](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/mtaulty/Prism--Silverlight-Part-1-Taking-Sketched-Code-Towards-Unity/). There is also source code for application made in last video.
Then you can combine knowledge from Southridge labs and this Prism tutorial.

Comment: I know it. But it does not cover prism, right? I'm looking for samples with prism and ribbon in the same application.

Comment: The problem is that I know how they work separately, it is the combination that I cannot implement correctly. But thanks a lot for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem this weekend and after much reading and searching came up with this code that I posted for review

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/429/mvvm-wpf-ribbon-v4-with-prism