# WPF how to integrate Ribbon in prism applications

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, modularity

I'm writing a prism application and would like to integrate Ribbon library in it. I want a Ribbon Window that would be used as a Shell with office-like tabs and tab groups. The modules should be loaded on demand depending on the tab selected by user. I don't want the tabs to be located in a region if this is avoidable. So I created a Ribbon window and some regions and get all kind of errors (cannot resolve dependency object, etc.). Is there somewhere a good example of such application or a tutorial? How to load the modules depending on the user's choice?

I started [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127328/wpf-prism-and-ribbon-samples-tutorials) but I didn't get an answer that could help me.

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Which Ribbon implementation are you wanting to use in this application?

Comment: This one http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=wpf&title=WPF%20Ribbon%20Preview

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented a RegionAdapter for the Ribbon? (I'm guessing you're trying to fill the Ribbon dynamically with a Region attached property)

See this [link](http://blogsprajeesh.blogspot.com/2009/09/prism-creating-custom-region-adapter.html) for details.

Comment: In fact I wanted the Ribbon tabs to be a static part of a shell window rather than treat them as one of the modules.

Comment: Okay - how do you determine which functionality goes into the Ribbon? Isn't that dependant on the modules available?

Answer (score 0):

Make your shell a RibbonWindow and if you need commands over the whole application you can create applicationcommands.