# WPF Prism and the Ribbon Control

Tags: .net, wpf, prism, ribbon

I am working on a line of business application for our company and I came across Prism.  I have never worked with it before but the concepts it talks about sound a lot like what I did for the last project in Winforms.  I had a ShellForm and then multiple User Controls.

Anyway, assuming I am not seriously misunderstanding what Prism is I would like to know how a Ribbon Control would fit into it.  Is it it's own `Module` with a `Region` on the `Shell.xaml` or is it embedded in the `Shell.xaml`?  It seems to me like it would be the second one but then again, I don't know what I am talking about yet or I wouldn't be asking.

Also, I don't suppose anyone else has used a Ribbon Control in an Enterprise Prism application before and could offer any tips or "watch-outs" about walking this path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Prism and Ribbon samples/tutorials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127328/wpf-prism-and-ribbon-samples-tutorials)

Comment: I have voted to close my own question.  I, somehow, missed the linked question.  Sadly though that one doesn't have the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely it would be in the Shell.xaml --- since the Ribbon control integrates with the window chrome in ways that I dont think would be possible if it was a modules (and part of a UserControl).

Refer to following to get the window chrome integration: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/08/04/why-should-i-use-a-ribbonwindow.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wpf/why-should-i-use-a-ribbonwindow)

That limits (at least from a design purist point of view) how the modules can interact with the ribbon control - but more than likely your design doesnt need that if you want to use a Ribbon in the first place.

Comment: So, if I am understanding correctly, I would actually use a `RibbonWindow` as my `Shell.xaml`, correct?

Comment: That would be root element in your shell.xaml

Answer (score 2):

The ribbon would be an child element of RibbonWindow, which would both be contained in shell.xaml. Your module would then just register Tabs, groups, or buttons to the regions you setup on your ribbon.

Check out this code review post for some sample code
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/429/mvvm-wpf-ribbon-v4-with-prism